# How do I create a deployment package for CodedUI Tests recorded in Visual Studio 2010 beta?

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2010, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

A few test scenarios have been recorded using CodedUI test template for my web application in Visual Studio 2010 beta. These run from within the Visual Studio successfully without any issues. **I was looking for instructions to create a deployment package.**

Comment: Unless I don't understand what you're asking by "deployment package", I believe my updated answer actually answers your question (if so, please select it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coded UI tests use namespaces within libraries that are part of Visual Studio e.g. `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting`

This is unlike [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) which is part of the core .NET framework e.g.

```
System.Windows.Automation
```

Therefore as I understand it you cannot package Coded UI tests to run in an environment that does not have Visual Studio installed.

Answer (score 5):

**Configure an environment with a "standalone" MSTest**

A series of [new test tools](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2009/10/visual-studio-2010-simplified-to-four-skus-beta-2-arrives.ars) is being introduced with Visual Studio 2010. [Team Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd648127%28VS.100%29.aspx#TestAgents) provides a very small footprint and includes **MSTest** (it will be installed in a Visual Studio path).

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe

You can copy the contents of your test project(s) `bin\` directory to the machine with Team Agents installed and execute MSTest against your test container.

> mstest /testcontainer:x:\test-project\automated-tests.dll"

Comment: Thank you ajmastream for replying.